# What the latest version published of an artifact?

Tags: maven

There's a way to list(no download) what the latest version published of an artifact?
If possible using a command or utility, I'm using Maven and Artifactory.

Thanks

Comment: Are you concerned with Maven Central or your private Artifactory?

Comment: I need this for private library published not for tirthparty library.

Answer (score 0):

I always just google the artifact name/id and "maven" to get to the artifact's page on whatever repo is hosting the artifact.  From there I can see dependencies and the exact  stanza I need for each of the available versions.

A tool or utility would have to be told which repo to search - a more complex invocation and less information than what google gives you.

Comment: @khmarbaise because sometimes maven artifacts are on other repos

Answer (score 0):

The best thing i could suggest is to use http://search.maven.org which is the search engine for Maven Central.

Apart from that the search enginge has a REST-API which can simply be used.